# java.lang.StackOverflowError- file uploading error

Tags: java, primefaces, stack-overflow

I'm facing a problem while working with primefaces, I made a UI for crud operations where I upload a pdf file as the content field of "media" entity, I'm adding the french version and then the same UI is rendered to add the english version, when saving the first "media" it goes well, the problem is when I add the english version, here's the stack trace

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
      org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:102)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

cause mère

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:433)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:874)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1478)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4204)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4103)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:213)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
```

well the stacktrace is not full but I guess it's enough to have and idea of what's going wrong.
here's the sode snipet where I'm uploading the pdf file:String name=new String();

```
try{
        System.out.println("Dans l'action fileUpload");
        String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("------------------"+path);
        path+="upload/media/";
        System.out.println("------------------"+path);
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        name = fmt.format(new Date())
                +  contentLink.getFileName().substring(contentLink.getFileName().lastIndexOf('.'));

        File file = new File(path + name);

        media.setContenu(name);
        InputStream is = contentLink.getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        is.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("upload termine");
```

thanks for your help,

Comment: To "Guess what's going wrong" some of your code would help

Comment: I edited the question, you can see the code snipet, thnks

Comment: Looks like your problem might not be related to primefaces upload but more to your DAO layer

Comment: I didn't know quite well the origine of the problem, it might be related to DAO layer, although it works when I add the first "media" .